# why i can't use xx[this.index].style.display? it's said "Cannot read property 'style' of undefinedbtn"

Tags: javascript, for-loop, this, getelementsbytagname, typeerror

i want to make xx[this.index] in a loop for making each one has an index and then when i click a button of them, the background of button would turn to yellow color & the div block would change the words at the same time. why it doesn't work? i saw other people use this way is working good. how can I do? thanks a lot!

here is my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QCxwr/7

```
 window.onload=function()
    {
        var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var div = document.getElementsByName('div');

        for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++) {
            btn[i].index = i;
            btn[i].onclick=function() {
                for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++) {
                    btn[i].className = '';
                    div[i].style.display='none';
                }
                this.className = 'active';
                div[this.index].style.display = 'block';
            };
        }
    };
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` is not getting what you think it's getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the updated javascript code. Your DIVs array is 0 as you fetch using "getElementsByName".

```
window.onload=function()
        {
            var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

            for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++) {
                btn[i].index = i;alert
                btn[i].onclick=function() {                
                    for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++) {
                        btn[i].className = '';
                        div[i].style.display='none';
                    }
                    this.className = 'active'; 
                    div[this.index].style.display = 'block';
                };
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` will refer to the window here. Unless you put a property index on the object window (really not advised) this won't work.

So if this function is executed in a method on a object you'll have to do the classic trick :

```
 var me = this;
 window.onload=function(){
     ...
     div[me.index].style.display = 'block';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DIV array is empty. Did you mean to use

```
getElementsByTagName
```

instead of

```
getElementsByName
```

when returning the DIVs?

Also You should check the array length before attempting to access.

Updated code http://jsfiddle.net/QCxwr/9/

Comment: Oops... yes! thank u... my eyes are too tired... i lost the 'tag'